# Store a Lambda expression with multiple possible out types in a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

**The problem:**

I have an html table with headers that include sort buttons.  The data is fetched at the controller and sorted with `OrderBy()` based off a passed route value (a string).  I'm currently using a gigantic switch statement that requires a `col_asc` and `col_desc` check for each column to determine the requested sort method.  I want to whittle this down as much as possible and add a `ThenBy` sort that will also be passed as a route value.

```
Func<MProduct,int> orderByLambda;
switch (orderByColName)
{
    case "asset_desc":
        //models = models.OrderByDescending(m => m.AssetId);
        orderByLambda = m => m.AssetId; // this is test code
        break;
    case "asset_asc":
        models = models.OrderBy(m => m.AssetId);

        break;
    case "location_desc":
        models = models.OrderByDescending(m => m.Locations.Name);
        break;
    case "location_asc":
        models = models.OrderBy(m => m.Locations.Name);
        break;

    ...... So on and so forth ......

    case "manufacturer_desc":
        models = models.OrderByDescending(m => m.Models.Manufacturers.Name);
        break;
    case "manufacturer_asc":
        models = models.OrderBy(m => m.Models.Manufacturers.Name);
        break;
    default:
        models = models.OrderByDescending(m => m.AssetId);
        break;
}
```

**The desired solution:**

What I would like to do is break this apart and only check the actual column name in the switch statement and use a `bool` to check the asc/desc part.  The switch statement would only assign the desired lambda expression to a variable (orderByLambda).  The ordering function would look something like this:

```
private IEnumerable<MProduct> Order(
    List<MProduct> items,
    bool isDescending,
    Func<MProduct, int> orderByLambda)
{
    if (isDescending)
    {
        return items.OrderByDescending(orderByLambda);
    }
    return items.OrderBy(orderByLambda);
}
```

**Where I'm stuck**

This appears to work so far (Visual Studio isn't showing any red). However, since I have to declare the lambda variable as type `Func<MProduct, int>`, I can't pass the columns who's datatype is not an `int`.  How can I overcome this?  Is there a better way?  I'm looking into the `dynamic` type but I'm not 100% sure that will work.

Comment: You can just change `Func<MProduct, int>` to `Func<MProduct, object>` and it should work fine in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make `Order` generic, but that would mean that the caller would need to specify the type of the column.

```
private IEnumerable<MProduct> Order<T>(List<MProduct> items, bool isDescending, Func<MProduct, T> orderByLambda)
{
    if (isDescending)
    {
        return items.OrderByDescending(orderByLambda);
    }
    return items.OrderBy(orderByLambda);
}
```

Another solution would be to not pass a func that is dependent on the column type. The `Order` method would take an `Action` with a parameter that has itself a generic method that will apply the appropriate order method:

```
private IEnumerable<MProduct> Order(List<MProduct> items, bool isDescending, Action<IApplyer<MProduct>> orderByLambda)
{
    IApplyer<MProduct> applyer;
    if (isDescending)
    {
        applyer = new OrderByApplyer<MProduct>(items);
    }
    else
    {
        applyer = new OrderDescendingByApplyer<MProduct>(items);
    }
    orderByLambda(applyer);
    return applyer.Result;
}

// Usage
Order(items, true, a => a.Apply(o => o.Name));
Order(items, true, a => a.Apply(o => o.Age));
Dictionary<string, Action<IApplyer<MProduct>>> columns = new Dictionary<string, Action<IApplyer<MProduct>>>
{
    ["Name"] = a => a.Apply(o => o.Name),
    ["Age"] = a => a.Apply(o => o.Age),
};
Order(items, true, columns["Age"]);

//Implementation

interface IApplyer<TTarget>
{
    void Apply<TColumn>(Func<TTarget, TColumn> orderBy);
    IOrderedEnumerable<TTarget> Result { get; }
}

class OrderByApplyer<TTarget> : IApplyer<TTarget>
{
    public OrderByApplyer(IEnumerable<TTarget> target)
    {
        this.Target = target;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TTarget> Target { get; }
    public IOrderedEnumerable<TTarget> Result { get; set; }

    public void Apply<TColumn>(Func<TTarget, TColumn> orderBy)
    {
        this.Result = this.Target.OrderBy(orderBy);
    }
}

class OrderDescendingByApplyer<TTarget> : IApplyer<TTarget>
{
    public OrderDescendingByApplyer(IEnumerable<TTarget> target)
    {
        this.Target = target;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TTarget> Target { get; }
    public IOrderedEnumerable<TTarget> Result { get; set; }

    public void Apply<TColumn>(Func<TTarget, TColumn> orderBy)
    {
        this.Result = this.Target.OrderByDescending(orderBy);
    }
}
class ThenByApplyer<TTarget> : IApplyer<TTarget>
{
    public ThenByApplyer(IOrderedEnumerable<TTarget> target)
    {
        this.Target = target;
    }

    public IOrderedEnumerable<TTarget> Target { get; }
    public IOrderedEnumerable<TTarget> Result { get; set; }

    public void Apply<TColumn>(Func<TTarget, TColumn> orderBy)
    {
        this.Result = this.Target.ThenBy(orderBy);
    }
}

class ThenByDescendingByApplyer<TTarget> : IApplyer<TTarget>
{
    public ThenByDescendingByApplyer(IOrderedEnumerable<TTarget> target)
    {
        this.Target = target;
    }

    public IOrderedEnumerable<TTarget> Target { get; }
    public IOrderedEnumerable<TTarget> Result { get; set; }

    public void Apply<TColumn>(Func<TTarget, TColumn> orderBy)
    {
        this.Result = this.Target.ThenByDescending(orderBy);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are quite a few things I like about this approach but it is a littler over my head at the moment.  It's late and I'm out of time for the night but I'll dig into it, learn a thing or two, and mark as accepted after that point.  Thanks!

Comment: @TylerSells Glad to help, if I can help with any info, don't hesitate to ask :)